# My Exception is not working even i already created an If else statement for it

Tags: java

So I made an exception on another class called EmptyInputException, so basically the purpose of this is to inform the user if they enter a space in their output. Any thoughts why it's not working for me. The EmptyInputException, it's meant for the users if they accidentaly input a space instead of letters then it should print the message from the exception but in my case it's not working. When i try to input a blank answer there is no print message from the EmptyInputException

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String questions[] = {"What is the color of the sky? ", "What is 1 + 1? ",
            "What is the capital of the Philippines? ", "Who is the current president of the Philippines? ",
            "What is the capital of Japan? ", "What is 2 + 3? ",
            "What is 9 + 1?", "What is the capital of the United States? ",
            "What is 10 + 10? ", "How many hand fingers do humans have? "};

    String choices[] = {"a","b","c"};

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    

    try {

        while(x<=9) {
            System.out.println("Choose a Letter: a , b , c");
            System.out.println("No." + (x+1) + " " + questions[x]);
            String answer = scan.next();
            x++;
            
            if(answer.equals(choices[0])) {
                scan.nextLine();

            } else if (answer.equals(choices[1])) {
                scan.nextLine();

            } else if (answer.equals(choices[2])) {
                scan.nextLine();

            } else if (answer.equals(" ")) {
                throw new EmptyInputException();

            } else {
                throw new InvalidLetterException();
            }   
    
        } 

    } catch(InvalidLetterException e) {
        System.out.println(); //Spacing
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(); //Spacing
        System.out.println("You can try again.");
        System.out.println(); //Spacing
        do {
            System.out.println("No." + (y+1) + " " + questions[y]);
            scan.next();
            y++;
        }while(y<=9);
        
    } catch (EmptyInputException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }



}
```

public class EmptyInputException extends Exception {

```
//QuizBee.java
public EmptyInputException() {
    super("ERROR : Please do not enter spaces.");
}

public EmptyInputException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

Comment: you should show the other class, the error is probably there

Comment: What does "is not working for me" exactly means??

Comment: What do you call "not working" ? What is the input ans the expected output ?

Comment: The EmptyInputException, it's meant for the users if they accidentaly input a space instead of letters then it should print the message from the exception but in my case it's not working. When i try to input a blank answer there is no print message from the EmptyInputException

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a Scanner with the default token delimiter, which its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) states

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
> which by default matches whitespace.

And you are using the `next()` method to read in user input. That method works as follows according to its official Documentation:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. **A
> complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
> delimiter pattern.** This method may block while waiting for input to
> scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

The next() method uses the delimiter, which is whitespace in your case, to determine where an input begins and ends. That means that with whitespace as a delimiter, the `next()` method will and can never return a whitespace itself, because that is the used delimiter.

You could try playing around with your delimiter, but I'd rather suggest just using `nextLine()` to read in your input and then check if result is blank to determine the user entered nothing or just whitespaces:

```
  String answer = scan.nextLine();
  if (answer.isBlank()) {
      throw new EmptyInputException();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you gave @OH GOD SPIDERS is very likely right. To see more evidence, change

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

into

```
System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
```

or more easily

```
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Once you know your code works you can still tweak the information that will be presented to the user.

Comment: Still not working sir, still no message from my exception when i input blank space. I'm guessing the problem is on my if statement on my EmptyInputException but idk what to change cause i think it's already right not sure tho

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) class.
It returns tokens but not the token delimiters. And per default (you did not configure anything else) the delimiters will match any whitespace.

Thus the line

```
String answer = scan.next();
```

will not return if only linefeeds or space characters are entered, and all the rest of your handling code goes unused.

To get out of that, configure the scanner to only use carriage returns as delimiters.